# type class NumberLike instance for Coproduct with shapeless

Tags: scala, types, functional-programming, typeclass, shapeless

I want to introduce a type class with comparison number like types, but also dates.

Here is my type class:

```
trait NumberLike[A] {
  def lessThenOrEqual[B](a: A, b: B): Boolean
  def moreThenOrEqual[B](a: A, b: B): Boolean
}

object NumberLike {
  def apply[A](implicit numericalLike: NumberLike[A]): NumberLike[A] =
    numericalLike

  def lessThenOrEqual[A: NumberLike, B](a: A)(b: B): Boolean =
    NumberLike[A].lessThenOrEqual(a, b)
  def moreThenOrEqual[A: NumberLike, B](a: A)(b: B): Boolean =
    NumberLike[A].moreThenOrEqual(a, b)

  def instance[A, B](
      lTOE: (A, B) => Boolean,
      mTOE: (A, B) => Boolean
  ): NumberLike[A] = new NumberLike[A] {
    def lessThenOrEqual[B](a: A, b: B): Boolean = lTOE(a, b)
    def moreThenOrEqual[B](a: A, b: B): Boolean = mTOE(a, b)
  }

  implicit class NumericalLikeOps[A: NumberLike](a: A) {
    def lessThenOrEqual[B](b: B): Boolean = NumberLike[A].lessThenOrEqual(a, b)
    def moreThenOrEqual[B](b: B): Boolean = NumberLike[A].moreThenOrEqual(a, b)
  }
}
```

The problem is that I want to have the function lessThenOrEqual(a,b) the posibility to put in another type, since I will make comparison between, for example, integers and floats available. Nonetheless the type class will be just one for each type, independently if I can comepare, for example, integers with more than one another type, lets say, integers and floats. Thus, the type B, is just function specifit and should not be a variable of the type class.

For the instance I will have the problem that the type B is not accepted as a function variable.

Is there any work around for this? Or in another words, how can I make the variable B just function-specific for lTOE in the instance definition?

---

**EDIT:**

I have used the following solution proposed by the solutions:

```
trait NumberLike[A] {
  type B
  def lessThenOrEqual(a: A, b: B): Boolean
  def moreThenOrEqual(a: A, b: B): Boolean
}

object NumberLike {
  type Aux[A, B0] = NumberLike[A] { type B = B0 }

  def apply[A, B](implicit numberLike: Aux[A, B]): Aux[A, B] =
    numberLike

  def lessThenOrEqual[A, B](a: A)(b: B)(
      implicit numberLike: Aux[A, B]): Boolean =
    numberLike.lessThenOrEqual(a, b)
  def moreThenOrEqual[A, B](a: A)(b: B)(
      implicit numberLike: Aux[A, B]): Boolean =
    numberLike.moreThenOrEqual(a, b)

  def instance[A, B0](
      lTOE: (A, B0) => Boolean,
      mTOE: (A, B0) => Boolean
  ): Aux[A, B0] = new NumberLike[A] {
    type B = B0
    def lessThenOrEqual(a: A, b: B): Boolean = lTOE(a, b)
    def moreThenOrEqual(a: A, b: B): Boolean = mTOE(a, b)
  }

  object ops {
    implicit class NumberLikeOps[A](a: A) {
      def lessThenOrEqual[B](b: B)(implicit numberLike: Aux[A, B]): Boolean =
        numberLike.lessThenOrEqual(a, b)
      def moreThenOrEqual[B](b: B)(implicit numberLike: Aux[A, B]): Boolean =
        numberLike.moreThenOrEqual(a, b)
    }
  }

  implicit val intIntNumberLike: Aux[Int, Int] = instance(_ <= _, _ >= _)
  implicit val intFloatNumberLike: Aux[Int, Float] = instance(_ <= _, _ >= _)
  implicit val DoubleDoubleNumberLike: Aux[Double, Double] = instance(_ <= _, _ >= _)
  implicit val floatFloatNumberLike: Aux[Float, Float] = instance(_ <= _, _ >= _)
}
```

And now I am trying to get an instance for the coproduct

```
type NumberLikeType = Int :+: Double :+: Float :+: CNil
```

What I am trying to define is by using shapeless are the functions lessThenOrEqual and moreThenOrEqual, but I do not get the solution. Here is what I tried:

```
implicit val cnilNumericalLike: NumberLike[CNil] =
    new NumberLike[CNil] {
      override def lessThenOrEqual(a: CNil, b: B): Boolean = true
      override def moreThenOrEqual(a: CNil, b: B): Boolean = true
    }

  implicit def coproductConsTransform[L, R, LL, RR <: Coproduct](
      implicit
      lch: NumberLike[L],
      lch2: NumberLike[LL],
      rch: NumberLike[R],
      rch2: NumberLike[RR]): NumberLike[L :+: R] =
    new NumberLike[L :+: R] {
      override def lessThenOrEqual(t: L :+: R, b: LL :+: RR): Boolean = {
        t match {
          case Inl(l) =>
            b match {
              case Inl(ll) => lch.lessThenOrEqual(l, ll)
              case Inr(rr) => lch.lessThenOrEqual(l, rr)
            }
          case Inr(r) => rch.lessThenOrEqual(r, b)
        }
      }

      override def moreThenOrEqual(t: L :+: R, b: L :+: R): Boolean = {
        t match {
          case Inl(l) =>
            b match {
              case Inl(bl) => lch.moreThenOrEqual(l, bl)
              case Inr(br) => false
            }
          case Inr(r) =>
            b match {
              case Inl(bl) => false
              case Inr(br) => rch.moreThenOrEqual(r, br)
            }
        }
      }
    }

  implicit def genericTransform[A, B](implicit
                                      gen: Generic.Aux[A, B],
                                      cch: Lazy[NumberLike[B]]): NumberLike[A] =
    new NumberLike[A] {
      def lessThenOrEqual(a: A, b: A): Boolean =
        cch.value.lessThenOrEqual(gen.to(a), gen.to(b))
      def moreThenOrEqual(a: A, b: A): Boolean =
        cch.value.moreThenOrEqual(gen.to(a), gen.to(b))
    }
```

I know that the input types are wrong, but do not know what to introduce else.

---

**EDIT2:**

I have tried several combinations, but even through

```
NumberLike[NumberLikeType, NumberLikeType]
```

gives the error: Error:(107, 29) diverging implicit expansion for type utils.NumberLike.NumberLike.Aux[Int,Int]
starting with method genericTransform in object NumberLike
    println(reify(NumberLike[NumberLikeType, NumberLikeType]))

```
import shapeless.{:+:, CNil, Coproduct, Generic, Inl, Inr, Lazy}

trait NumberLike[A] {
  type B
  def lessThenOrEqual(a: A, b: B): Boolean
  def moreThenOrEqual(a: A, b: B): Boolean
}

object NumberLike {
  type Aux[A, B0] = NumberLike[A] { type B = B0 }

  def apply[A, B](implicit numberLike: Aux[A, B]): Aux[A, B] =
    numberLike

  def lessThenOrEqual[A, B](a: A)(b: B)(
      implicit numberLike: Aux[A, B]): Boolean =
    numberLike.lessThenOrEqual(a, b)
  def moreThenOrEqual[A, B](a: A)(b: B)(
      implicit numberLike: Aux[A, B]): Boolean =
    numberLike.moreThenOrEqual(a, b)

  def instance[A, B0](
      lTOE: (A, B0) => Boolean,
      mTOE: (A, B0) => Boolean
  ): Aux[A, B0] = new NumberLike[A] {
    type B = B0
    def lessThenOrEqual(a: A, b: B): Boolean = lTOE(a, b)
    def moreThenOrEqual(a: A, b: B): Boolean = mTOE(a, b)
  }

  object ops {
    implicit class NumberLikeOps[A](a: A) {
      def lessThenOrEqual[B](b: B)(implicit numberLike: Aux[A, B]): Boolean =
        numberLike.lessThenOrEqual(a, b)
      def moreThenOrEqual[B](b: B)(implicit numberLike: Aux[A, B]): Boolean =
        numberLike.moreThenOrEqual(a, b)
    }
  }

  implicit val intIntNumberLike: Aux[Int, Int] = instance(_ <= _, _ >= _)
  implicit val intFloatNumberLike: Aux[Int, Float] = instance(_ <= _, _ >= _)
  implicit val intDoubleNumberLike: Aux[Int, Double] = instance(_ <= _, _ >= _)
  implicit val DoubleIntNumberLike: Aux[Double, Int] = instance(_ <= _, _ >= _)
  implicit val DoubleFloatNumberLike: Aux[Double, Float] = instance(_ <= _, _ >= _)
  implicit val DoubleDoubleNumberLike: Aux[Double, Double] = instance(_ <= _, _ >= _)
  implicit val floatIntNumberLike: Aux[Float, Int] = instance(_ <= _, _ >= _)
  implicit val floatFloatNumberLike: Aux[Float, Float] = instance(_ <= _, _ >= _)
  implicit val floatDoubleNumberLike: Aux[Float, Double] = instance(_ <= _, _ >= _)
  implicit val cnilNumericalLike: Aux[CNil, CNil] = instance((_, _) => true, (_, _) => true)
  implicit val intCnilNumericalLike: Aux[Int, CNil] = instance((_, _) => true, (_, _) => true)
  implicit val floatCnilNumericalLike: Aux[Float, CNil] = instance((_, _) => true, (_, _) => true)
  implicit val doubleCnilNumericalLike: Aux[Double, CNil] = instance((_, _) => true, (_, _) => true)
  implicit val cnilIntNumericalLike: Aux[CNil, Int] = instance((_, _) => true, (_, _) => true)
  implicit val cnilFloatNumericalLike: Aux[CNil, Float] = instance((_, _) => true, (_, _) => true)
  implicit val cnilDoubleNumericalLike: Aux[CNil, Double] = instance((_, _) => true, (_, _) => true)



  implicit def coproductConsTransform[L, R <: Coproduct, LL, RR <: Coproduct](
      implicit
      lch: Aux[L, LL],
      lch1: Aux[L, RR],
      rch: Aux[R, LL :+: RR],
      lch2: Aux[L, LL :+: RR],
      rch1: Aux[R, RR],
      rch2: Aux[R, LL],
      ua: Aux[L :+: R, LL],
      ua2: Aux[L :+: R, RR]): Aux[L :+: R, LL :+: RR] =
    instance(
      {
        case (Inl(l), Inl(ll)) => lch.lessThenOrEqual(l, ll)
        case (Inl(l), Inr(rr)) => lch1.lessThenOrEqual(l, rr)
        case (Inr(r), Inl(ll)) => rch2.lessThenOrEqual(r, ll)
        case (Inr(r), Inr(rr)) => rch1.lessThenOrEqual(r, rr)
      }, {
        case (Inl(l), Inl(ll)) => lch.moreThenOrEqual(l, ll)
        case (Inl(l), Inr(rr)) => lch1.moreThenOrEqual(l, rr)
        case (Inr(r), Inl(ll)) => rch2.moreThenOrEqual(r, ll)
        case (Inr(r), Inr(rr)) => rch1.moreThenOrEqual(r, rr)
      }
    )
  implicit def coproductConsTransform2[L,R <: Coproduct, CNil]
  (
     implicit
     lch: Aux[L, CNil],
     rch: Aux[R, CNil]
  ): Aux[L :+: R, CNil] =
    instance(
      {
        case (Inl(l), _) => true
        case (Inr(r), _) => true
      }, {
        case (Inl(l), _) => true
        case (Inr(r), _) => true
      }
    )

  implicit def coproductConsTransform3[L,R <: Coproduct, CNil]
  (
    implicit
    lch: Aux[L, CNil],
    rch: Aux[R, CNil]
  ): Aux[CNil, L :+: R] =
    instance(
      {
        case ( _, Inl(l)) => true
        case ( _, Inr(r)) => true
      }, {
        case ( _, Inl(l)) => true
        case ( _, Inr(r)) => true
      }
    )

  implicit def genericTransform[A, B, ARepr, BRepr](
      implicit
      gen: Generic.Aux[A, ARepr],
      gen1: Generic.Aux[B, BRepr],
      cch: Lazy[Aux[ARepr, BRepr]]): Aux[A, B] =
    instance(
      (a, b) => cch.value.lessThenOrEqual(gen.to(a), gen1.to(b)),
      (a, b) => cch.value.moreThenOrEqual(gen.to(a), gen1.to(b))
    )
}
```

Comment: Technically speaking comparisons between different types are always false. Thus they should not make sense at all. I would just leave it like `trait NumberLike[A]`. But if you insists in having two types, you could move the `B` to the method level `def lessThanOrEqual[B](a: A, b: B): Boolean`, however that would mean that each implementation should be able to handle any kind of B which can be tricky. Other option would be to make `B` a **type member** and use the **aux** pattern, but at the end it would not be as different as you already have.

Comment: Yes I will do implicitly convertions, when I want to compare double and Int, I will convert the int implicitly to an double. But I want to make this conversion as implicit in each instance. My problem is that I do not know how to write the instance definition of the function if the type of B is defined on the method level as you say.

Comment: the definition: def instance[A, B](
      lTOE: (A, B) => Boolean,
      mTOE: (A, B) => Boolean
  ) is wrong, since B here is not defined by the variable I put in, but by the instance. Lets say B is not defined here on the method level...How could I fix that?

Comment: I just noticed that you already have the `B` at method level, I was confused. Sorry. it would be good if you describe how would you like to use this. But I am almost sure that what is the best for you is to use a `multiple-parameter type class` _(like Dmytro showed)_.

Comment: The unique problem with multiple-parameter type class is that I need a instance for generics (a HList from shapeless) and this might be too tricky (for me) :(

Comment: what do you mean with generics and HList? I do not see any of that here. Again, it would be good if you can edit your question to provide more information about how do you want to use this.

Comment: Ok I will add some further information later.

Comment: Why don't you use the built-in type classes? You can achieve this easily by using `Ordering.lteq` and `Ordering.gteq`: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Ordering.html

Comment: @texasbruce I was looking for that, but I want to implement the same for dates, so Ordering is not working for dates as far as I know.

Comment: You can easily write your own instance of Ordering[Date] and provide as implicit. No need to write another type class.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have multiple-parameter type class.

```
trait NumberLike[A, B] {
  def lessThenOrEqual(a: A, b: B): Boolean
  def moreThenOrEqual(a: A, b: B): Boolean
}

object NumberLike {
  def apply[A, B](implicit numberLike: NumberLike[A, B]): NumberLike[A, B] =
    numberLike

  def lessThenOrEqual[A, B](a: A)(b: B)(implicit numberLike: NumberLike[A, B]): Boolean =
    numberLike.lessThenOrEqual(a, b)
  def moreThenOrEqual[A, B](a: A)(b: B)(implicit numberLike: NumberLike[A, B]): Boolean =
    numberLike.moreThenOrEqual(a, b)

  def instance[A, B](
                      lTOE: (A, B) => Boolean,
                      mTOE: (A, B) => Boolean
                    ): NumberLike[A, B] = new NumberLike[A, B] {
    def lessThenOrEqual(a: A, b: B): Boolean = lTOE(a, b)
    def moreThenOrEqual(a: A, b: B): Boolean = mTOE(a, b)
  }

  object ops {
    implicit class NumberLikeOps[A, B](a: A) {
      def lessThenOrEqual(b: B)(implicit numberLike: NumberLike[A, B]): Boolean = numberLike.lessThenOrEqual(a, b)
      def moreThenOrEqual(b: B)(implicit numberLike: NumberLike[A, B]): Boolean = numberLike.moreThenOrEqual(a, b)
    }
  }

  implicit val intIntNumberLike: NumberLike[Int, Int] = instance(_ <= _, _ >= _)
  implicit val intFloatNumberLike: NumberLike[Int, Float] = instance(_ <= _, _ >= _)
}

import NumberLike.ops._
1 lessThenOrEqual 2
1 lessThenOrEqual 2.0f
```

Also you can move `B` to type members as @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez advised

```
trait NumberLike[A] {
  type B
  def lessThenOrEqual(a: A, b: B): Boolean
  def moreThenOrEqual(a: A, b: B): Boolean
}

object NumberLike {
  type Aux[A, B0] = NumberLike[A] { type B = B0 }

  def apply[A, B](implicit numberLike: Aux[A, B]): Aux[A, B] =
    numberLike

  def lessThenOrEqual[A, B](a: A)(b: B)(implicit numberLike: Aux[A, B]): Boolean =
    numberLike.lessThenOrEqual(a, b)
  def moreThenOrEqual[A, B](a: A)(b: B)(implicit numberLike: Aux[A, B]): Boolean =
    numberLike.moreThenOrEqual(a, b)

  def instance[A, B0](
                      lTOE: (A, B0) => Boolean,
                      mTOE: (A, B0) => Boolean
                    ): Aux[A, B0] = new NumberLike[A] {
    type B = B0
    def lessThenOrEqual(a: A, b: B): Boolean = lTOE(a, b)
    def moreThenOrEqual(a: A, b: B): Boolean = mTOE(a, b)
  }

  object ops {
    implicit class NumberLikeOps[A](a: A) {
      def lessThenOrEqual[B](b: B)(implicit numberLike: Aux[A, B]): Boolean = numberLike.lessThenOrEqual(a, b)
      def moreThenOrEqual[B](b: B)(implicit numberLike: Aux[A, B]): Boolean = numberLike.moreThenOrEqual(a, b)
    }
  }

  implicit val intIntNumberLike: Aux[Int, Int] = instance(_ <= _, _ >= _)
  implicit val intFloatNumberLike: Aux[Int, Float] = instance(_ <= _, _ >= _)
}

import NumberLike.ops._
1 lessThenOrEqual 2
1 lessThenOrEqual 2.0f
```

If you keep `B` on method level you can't use constructor method `instance` (there are no polymorphic functions in Scala 2, they [will appear](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/4672) only in Scala 3). You should create instances via `new`. Also it's not clear how you are going to define instances, e.g. how to compare `Int` with arbitrary `B`.

```
trait NumberLike[A] {
  def lessThenOrEqual[B](a: A, b: B): Boolean
  def moreThenOrEqual[B](a: A, b: B): Boolean
}

object NumberLike {
  def apply[A](implicit numberLike: NumberLike[A]): NumberLike[A] =
    numberLike

  def lessThenOrEqual[A: NumberLike, B](a: A)(b: B): Boolean =
    NumberLike[A].lessThenOrEqual(a, b)
  def moreThenOrEqual[A: NumberLike, B](a: A)(b: B): Boolean =
    NumberLike[A].moreThenOrEqual(a, b)

  object ops {
    implicit class NumberLikeOps[A: NumberLike](a: A) {
      def lessThenOrEqual[B](b: B): Boolean = NumberLike[A].lessThenOrEqual(a, b)
      def moreThenOrEqual[B](b: B): Boolean = NumberLike[A].moreThenOrEqual(a, b)
    }
  }

  implicit val intNumberLike: NumberLike[Int] = new NumberLike[Int] {
    override def lessThenOrEqual[B](a: Int, b: B): Boolean = ???
    override def moreThenOrEqual[B](a: Int, b: B): Boolean = ???
  }
}
```

---

Try

```
implicit val cnilNumericalLike: Aux[CNil, CNil] = instance((_,_) => true, (_,_) => true)

implicit def coproductConsTransform[L, R <: Coproduct, LL, RR <: Coproduct](implicit
                                                                            lch: Aux[L, LL],
                                                                            lch1: Aux[L, RR],
                                                                            rch: Aux[R, LL :+: RR],
                                                                            rch1: Aux[R, RR],
                                                                           ): Aux[L :+: R, LL :+: RR] =
  instance({
    case (Inl(l), Inl(ll)) => lch.lessThenOrEqual(l, ll)
    case (Inl(l), Inr(rr)) => lch1.lessThenOrEqual(l, rr)
    case (Inr(r), b)       => rch.lessThenOrEqual(r, b)
  }, {
    case (Inl(l), Inl(bl)) => lch.moreThenOrEqual(l, bl)
    case (Inl(l), Inr(br)) => false
    case (Inr(r), Inl(bl)) => false
    case (Inr(r), Inr(br)) => rch1.moreThenOrEqual(r, br)
  })

implicit def genericTransform[A, B, ARepr, BRepr](implicit
                                                   gen: Generic.Aux[A, ARepr],
                                                   gen1: Generic.Aux[B, BRepr],
                                                   cch: Lazy[Aux[ARepr, BRepr]]
                                                  ): Aux[A, B] =
  instance(
    (a, b) => cch.value.lessThenOrEqual(gen.to(a), gen1.to(b)),
    (a, b) => cch.value.moreThenOrEqual(gen.to(a), gen1.to(b))
  )
```

Comment: Thas is not exactly what I am looking for. I just want B to be defined on the method level. The problem is that in the instance definition this is dificult to define.

Comment: @Patricio If you keep `B` on method level you can't use constructor method `instance`. You should create instances via `new`. Also it's not clear how you are going to define instances, e.g. how to compare `Int` with arbitrary `B`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I edited my question by using your answer.

Comment: @Patricio `Int :+: Double :+: Float :+: CNil` is not an HList, it's a Coproduct. HList would be `Int :: Double :: Float :: HNil`.

Comment: @Patricio See update. Once again, your type class `NumberLike` is two-parameter (either `NumberLike[A, B]` or `NumberLike.Aux[A, B]`). So you should define implicits not for `NumberLike` but for `Aux`-type.

Comment: I tried this but it does not work. Could you try to compile it by taken something like Coproduct[NumberLikeType](1) ?

Comment: @Patricio Well, this means that your logic in `coproductConsTransform` is wrong. Now in order to have instance `Aux[L :+: R, LL :+: RR]` you should have all 4 instances `Aux[L, LL]`, `Aux[L, RR]`, `Aux[R, LL :+: RR]`, and `Aux[R, RR]`. Why is it supposed to work? For example you have `NumberLike[CNil, CNil]`. But why will you have `NumberLike[CNil, Int :+: CNil]` or `NumberLike[Int :+: CNil, CNil]` or `NumberLike[Int :+: CNil, Int :+: CNil]`?

Comment: I tried many combinations and did not get it work, does you have any idea for this, @dmytro-mitin?

Comment: @Patricio Well, this depends on your logic. Write one of combinations you tried and we can try to see why it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have added an EDIT 2. I just focused on the less function, which is why the other (moreThanOrEqual) is set to true everything.

Comment: @Patricio Start with `NumberLike[CNil, CNil]`, `NumberLike[Int :+: CNil, CNil]`, `NumberLike[CNil, Int :+: CNil]`, `NumberLike[Int :+: CNil, Int :+: CNil]`... What is your logic? How do you compare `CNil` with `Int :+: CNil`? Look at your `coproductConsTransform`. It says that in order to have `Aux[L :+: R, LL :+: RR]` you need 8 implicits `Aux[L, LL]`, `Aux[L, RR]`, ..., `Aux[L :+: R, RR]`. Do you really mean this? Isn't it too many? How does this work for `NumberLike[Int :+: CNil, Int :+: CNil]`? I guess there are 4 cases (Inl,Inl),(Inl,Inr),(Inr,Inl),(Inr,Inr). Why do you have more cases?

Comment: @Patricio There is standard way to debug implicits. You can always resolve them manually. Start with some simple case and try to resolve implicits manually (explicitly) and you'll see why your code doesn't compile. I guess now you have issues with your logic of comparison. There should be 4 implicits `Aux[CNil, CNil]`, `Aux[L :+: R, CNil]`, `Aux[CNil, LL :+: RR]`, `Aux[L :+: R, LL :+: RR]` (with pattern matching specific for each particular implicit).

Comment: do you mean just for cases or four different implicits with its cases? Which cases should have each implicit?

Comment: @Patricio 4 different implicits with their cases. `Aux[CNil, CNil]`:  1 case, `Aux[L :+: R, CNil]`: 2 cases, `Aux[CNil, LL :+: RR]`: 2 cases, `Aux[L :+: R, LL :+: RR]`: 4 cases.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much :) I learnt very much from that :)

Comment: @Patricio In `coproductConsTransform2` you don't use `lch`, `rch` so you don't need them. Similarly for `coproductConsTransform3`. In `coproductConsTransform` you still have too many implicit parameters. I guess you need only `Aux[L, LL]`,`Aux[L, RR]`, `Aux[R, LL]`, `Aux[R, RR]`. Standard way to fight against divergence is `shapeless.Lazy` (see [book](https://books.underscore.io/shapeless-guide/shapeless-guide.html#implicit-divergence), section 3.4.1) and by-name implicits (in 2.13 [link](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/byname-implicits.html) [link](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/6050)).